# reading json file in c

Tags: c, json

i'm trying to extract data from json file  which continent  [ { "name": "alice", "age": 30, "freinds" : ["marc","max" ,"alice"] } ]
with this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<json-c/json.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[1024];
    struct json_object *parsed_json;
    struct json_object *name;
    struct json_object *age;
    struct json_object *friends;
    struct json_object *friend;
    size_t n_friends;

    size_t i;   

    fp = fp = fopen("file.json","r");
    if ( fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("UNable to open file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fread(buffer, 1024, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    parsed_json = json_tokener_parse(buffer);

    json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "name", &name);
    json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "age", &age);
    json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "friends", &friends);

    printf("Name: %s\n", json_object_get_string(name));
    printf("Age: %d\n", json_object_get_int(age));

    n_friends = json_object_array_length(friends);
    printf("Found %lu friends\n",n_friends);

    for(i=0;i<n_friends;i++) {
    friend = json_object_array_get_idx(friends, i);
    printf("%lu. %s\n",i+1,json_object_get_string(friend));
    }   
}
```

but I have this error while executing the code

```
Name: (null)
Age: 0
test: json_object.c:1214: json_object_array_length: Assertion `json_object_get_type(jso) == json_type_array' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: What is your input data?

Comment: Aside: please use `%zu` to output `size_t`. So `printf("Found %zu friends\n", n_friends);`

Comment: it's a JSON file

Comment: @ingab More specific -- show an example of the JSON input.

Comment: Isn't the first argument to [json_object_array_get_idx()](https://json-c.github.io/json-c/json-c-0.12/doc/html/json__object_8h.html#a5c9120a6d644ea12a61e2ec8520130c6) supposed to be a pointer? You are passing `size_t friends`.

Comment: [
    {
      "name": "alice",
      "age": 30,
      "freinds" : ["marc","max" ,"alice"]
 
    }

]

Comment: @ingab In this case the `parsed_json` is an array that contains an object. You need to extract the object using `json_object_array_get_idx(parsed_json, 0)` or get rid of the array altogether

Comment: `freinds` != `friends`. You should handle errors in your code - you will know then that `friends` was not found and you will find bugs sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong per se in the code you posted, The problem is in the input you provided.

The correct input string should be `{ "name": "alice", "age": 30, "friends" : ["marc","max" ,"alice"] }`.

If you do want the head object of the json to be an array then you need to use `json_object_array_get_idx` on `parsed_json` to get the underlying object.

To mitigate future programming errors I strongly recommend type checking of `json_object`s using `assert` or an if statement. Example:

```c
if ((type = json_object_get_type(object)) != json_type_array)
    fprintf(stderr, "Expected a %s but found %s\n",
        json_type_to_name(json_type_array), json_type_to_name(type));
```

Comment: so i must  parsed_json_1 = json_object_array_get_idx(parsed_json,1)to extract the first object ? ;

Comment: @ingab Almost, arrays are 0-indexed so you need to call `parsed_json_1 = json_object_array_get_idx(parsed_json, 0)` to get the first (and only) object

Comment: it shows this erreur  json_object_array_get_idx: Assertion `json_object_get_type(jso) == json_type_array' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Did you remember to change "freinds" to "friends"?